# Match two arrays and merge them comparing key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two different arrays. One is like:

```
const arrOne = [
    [{sender: '0000', to: '1111'}],
    [{sender: '2222', to: '1111'}]
];
```

And the other array is like:

```
const arrTwo = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    num: '1111'
  }
]
```

Now i want to match the key `to` from arrOne and `num` from array two and if they mathes, the first array should update with firstname and lastname. So, the expected output would be like this:

```
  const arrOne = [
        [{sender: '0000', to: '1111', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}],
        [{sender: '2222', to: '1111', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}]
    ];
```

Here's what i have tried:

```
arrOne = arrOne.map(item => {
  const item2 = arrTwo.find(i2 => i2.num == item.to);
  return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
});
```

Thanks in advance. Also please suggest how to do that with types in TypeScript ?

Comment: Was it intentional to have `LastName` in arrTwo, but `lastName` (lowercase `l`) in the result?

Answer (score 0):

This technique will filter out just the unwanted 'num' property:

```js
const arrOne = [[{sender: '0000', to: '1111'}],[{sender: '2222', to: '1111'}]];
const arrTwo = [{firstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe',num: '1111'}];
console.log(arrOne.map(i=>[{...i[0], ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(
  arrTwo.find(j=>j.num===i[0].to)??{}).filter(([k,v])=>k!=='num')
    .map(([k,v])=>[k==='LastName'?'lastName':k, v]))}]));
```

If you need to rename the 'LastName' property to 'lastName', you can alternatively do:

```js
const arrOne = [[{sender: '0000', to: '1111'}],[{sender: '2222', to: '1111'}]];
const arrTwo = [{firstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe',num: '1111'}];
console.log(arrOne.map((i,o)=>[{...i[0], ...(o=(arrTwo.find(j=>j.num===i[0].to)),
    (!o?{}:{firstName: o.firstName, lastName: o.LastName}))}]));
```

Both techniques are resilient to situations where there is no `num` match found.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arrOne` is an array of arrays so you need to account for that. I also assume you need to exclude `num` from `arrTwo` elements as per your expected output.

```js
let arrOne = [
    [{sender: '0000', to: '1111'}],
    [{sender: '2222', to: '1111'}]
];

const arrTwo = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    num: '1111'
  }
];

arrOne = arrOne.map(item => {
  const item2 = arrTwo.find(i2 => i2.num == item[0].to);
  return item2 ? [{ ...item[0], firstName: item2.firstName, lastName: item2.lastName }] : item;
});

console.log(arrOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost success,just need to change `item` to `item[0]`(because data in `arrOne` is nested array),and add `[]` to wrap the returned result

```js
let arrOne = [
    [{sender: '0000', to: '1111'}],
    [{sender: '2222', to: '1111'}]
]; // it's nested array here
const arrTwo = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Doe',
    num: '1111'
  }
]

arrOne = arrOne.map(item => {
  const item2 = arrTwo.find(i2 => i2.num == item[0].to)
  return item2 ? [{ ...item[0], ...item2 }] : [item[0]]; // need to return as array
});

console.log(arrOne)
```

Comment: Can you do that with type declaration i mean with typescript? @lucumt

Comment: @TanmoySarker You have not say typescript in your question,you need to update your question

Comment: I did that. I'm getting errors for the types @lucumt

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code,

```js
 const arrOne = [
    [{ sender: "0000", to: "1111" }],
    [{ sender: "2222", to: "1111" }],
  ];
  const arrTwo = [
    {
      firstName: "John",
      LastName: "Doe",
      num: "1111",
    },
  ];
  const newarrtt = () => {
    let val;
    const newarry = arrOne.map(item => {
      val = arrTwo.find(x => {
        return x.num, item[0].to;
      });

      if (val) {
        return [
          {
            ...item[0],
            firstName: val.firstName,
            LastName: val.LastName,
          },
        ];
      }

      val = null;
    });
    console.log(newarry);
  };
  newarrtt();
```

You missed thing is,You map function is not return object ,it is array.so you need to access such as item[0].

Answer (score 0):

A variant with forEach

```js
const arrOne = [
   [{ sender: '0000', to: '1111' }],
   [{ sender: '2222', to: '1111' }]
];

const arrTwo = [
   {
      firstName: 'John',
      LastName: 'Doe',
      num: '1111'
   }
];

arrOne.forEach(one => {
   const item = arrTwo.find(two => Number(two.num) === Number(one[0].to));
   if(item) one[0] = { ...one[0], ...item };
});

console.log(arrOne);
```